# URL Parameter Not Recognized in Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm learning MVC 4, and it's my understanding that going to this URL should pass an int of 44 to the Edit() method of the controller. Indeed, when I go here:

```
http://localhost:51921/TrackerJob/Edit/44
```

... this method gets invoked:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int trackerJobId = -1)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(trackerJobId);
}
```

... but the parameter is always -1. I had this working in a different project, but for some reason it's always -1 in this project. I don't see a difference between the two projects that would cause one to work and this one to fail. If I change the method signature to this:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int trackerJobId)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(trackerJobId);
}
```

I get an error:

`The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'trackerJobId' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32'`

Any ideas? I'm not sure what to check...

**Edit - Including routes, by request***

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: My first suspicion would be the routing. What happens if you browse to `http://localhost:51921/TrackerJob/Edit?trackerJobId=44`

Comment: Show us your routes from `Global.asax`. If you haven't changed them at all, then try changing the signature of your `ActionMethod` to `public ActionResult Edit(int Id)` as that is covered by the default route.

Comment: @DuncanHowe Your suggestion made it work. Now onto this Global.asax thingy...

Comment: @Dommer I edited my question to show the RouteConfig class. Does this mean that my parameter name has to be id, and it can't be trackerJobId?

Comment: Yes, unless you add a new route.

Comment: Thanks, guys. If anyone wants to provide that as an answer, I'll accept...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use the default routing then just make sure your parameter is called `id`.

Otherwise you could add a new route like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "TrackerJob",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{jobtrackerid}",
    defaults: new { controller = "TrackerJob", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Make sure you add this route BEFORE the default route. The order of routes is very important!

Only you know if the `trackerJobId` is optional or not.

Note that if you want something more fancy you can tweak the routes to produce what you want.

e.g. If you want URLs like `http://localhost:51921/TJ-E-44` for editing then your route would look like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "TrackerJobEdit",
    url: "TJ-E-{jobtrackerid}",
    defaults: new { controller = "TrackerJob", action = "Edit", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

I'm sure you get the idea.

Comment: Thank you. And just for my own sanity, I want to note that I can get around doing this by changing the parameter name from trackerJobId to id.